# Speed up string filtering in R

Tags: r, string, dplyr, sapply, stringr

I have a dataframe with a column of codes separated by commas. I am currently filtering this dataframe by looking through the code column and if a code appears from the list, I keep that row. My issue is that this dataframe is expanding, as is the list of acceptable codes, so I'd like to speed this process up if possible. Ideally there would be a way to mark a row as already checked and if a good code was in the row, then to not have to check it again for all the other acceptable codes.

Current dataframe looks something like this:

```
Code_column
,12ab,
,12ab,123b,
,456t,345u,
,12ab,789p,
```

list of good codes:

```
good_codes <- c(',123b,', ',456t,', ',345u,')
```

My filtering process currently:

```
df %>%
filter(sapply(`Code_column`, 
            function(x) any(sapply(good_codes, str_detect, string = x))) == TRUE)
```

Final column

```
Code_column
,12ab,123b,
,456t,345u,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we do not need `sapply`

```
df[str_detect(df$Code_column,paste(good_codes, collapse = '|')),]
[1] ",12ab,123b," ",456t,345u,"
```

You can pass | & to `str_detect`

```
paste(good_codes, collapse = '|')
[1] ",123b,|,456t,|,345u,"
```

Comment: I think this is also `df[ grepl(paste(good_codes, collapse='|'), df$CCode_column),]` in base R.